# Scatter small numbers in matplotlib doesn't scale axis correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use scatter to plot small numbers, the plot is "squeezed".
I think it will be easier to understand with the following code snippet:

```
a = np.random.randint(100, size=(50)) / 1000000
b =  np.random.randint(100, size=(50))

figure(figsize=(4,4))
plt.scatter(a,b)

figure(figsize=(4,4))
plt.plot(a,b, marker='o',linestyle='none')
```

The Scatter X axis is not scaled correctly to the data, how can I fix it ?

[image]

Comment: When I plot your example, I don't get the same issue (the graph is scaled automatically). It looks like you have something [like this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/navigation_toolbar.html), which maybe is affecting the default behavior?  But can you try enforcing the limits with `plt.xlim(min(a), max(a))`, or `plt.xlim(min(a) - x, max(a) + x)`, where `x` is a fraction of the range of the data?

Comment: tnx, it solved the issue (xlim thing ... ), maybe it is faulty old version. I'll try to upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I plot your example, I don't get the same issue (the graph is scaled automatically). It looks like you have something [like this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/navigation_toolbar.html), which maybe is affecting the default behavior? But can you try enforcing the limits with `plt.xlim(min(a), max(a))`, or `plt.xlim(min(a) - x, max(a) + x)`, where `x` is a fraction of the range of the data.